# excel macro search for word and copy sentence

Tags: macos, vba, excel

I hope someone can help me with this problem.

I have two documents, one is Word and one is Excel. In the word file I have a list of items, for example:

> Title Subtitle
>
> ```
> 1. Name
>
>    Address:
>
>    Phone number:
>
> 2. Name
>
>    Address:
>
>    Phone number:
>
> 3. Name
>
>    Address:
>
>    Phone number:
> ```

In the excel file I have a list of words in column D. What I want to do is take the word from column D, search for it in the Word document and then copy the sentence from after "Address: " to the ".", put that in Column C (i.e., one cell to the left), and then copy the sentence from after "Phone number: " to the "." and put it in Column B.

One of the parts I can't really wrap my head around is going from the first set of name, address and phone number to the next set.

Can someone help me with the macro on how to do this?

I have thought of expanding it from this:

```
Sub wordSearch()

' Purpose: display the text between (but not including)
' the words "Title" and "Address" if they both appear.
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim strTheText As String

    Set rng1 = ActiveDocument.Range
    If rng1.Find.Execute(FindText:="Example:") Then
        Set rng2 = ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.End, ActiveDocument.Range.End)
        If rng2.Find.Execute(FindText:=".") Then
            strTheText = ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.End, rng2.Start).Text
            MsgBox strTheText
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please clarify, it's necessary to get text from Excel column D cell, then find in Word the item with the name exactly equal to that text, and copy the phone and the addres to Excel?

Comment: Hi omegastripes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, the sub for Excel below gets whole text from `catalog.doc` located in the same folder as Excel file, parses text with `RegExp`, loops through contacts and puts it into the `Dictionary`, then loops through `D2:D10` cells and assign appropriate data for matched names to `C` and `B` columns respectively. Tested in MS Office 2003, Windows 7 HB.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetFromWord()

    ' Tools - References - add these:
    ' Microsoft Word 11.0 Object Library
    ' Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
    ' Microsoft Scripting Runtime

    Dim strCont As String
    Dim objCatalog As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim objMatch As IMatch2
    Dim objElt As Range

    With New Word.Application
        .Documents.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\catalog.doc"
        With .ActiveDocument.Range
            .WholeStory
            strCont = .Text
        End With
        .Quit
    End With
    Set objCatalog = New Scripting.Dictionary
    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = "\d+\.[ \t]*([^\n\r]*)\s*Address:[ \t]*([^\n\r]*)\s*Phone number:[ \t]*([^\n\r]*)\s*"
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        For Each objMatch In .Execute(strCont)
            objCatalog.Add objMatch.SubMatches(0), Array(objMatch.SubMatches(1), objMatch.SubMatches(2))
        Next
    End With
    For Each objElt In Range("D2:D10")
        With objElt
            If objCatalog.Exists(.Cells(1, 1).Value) Then
                .Offset(0, -1) = objCatalog(.Cells(1, 1).Value)(0)
                .Offset(0, -2) = objCatalog(.Cells(1, 1).Value)(1)
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Note, that duplicated contacts in Word will result in error, no additional check implemented.

**UPD:** In case of any problems with early binding you can use late binding `CreateObject(ProgID)` as follows, but it isn't a best practice in VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetFromWordLBind()

    Dim strCont As String
    Dim objCatalog, objMatch, objElt As Object

    With CreateObject("Word.Application")
        .Documents.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\catalog.docx"
        With .ActiveDocument.Range
            .WholeStory
            strCont = .Text
        End With
        .Quit
    End With
    Set objCatalog = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "\d+\.[ \t]*([^\n\r]*)\s*Address:[ \t]*([^\n\r]*)\s*Phone number:[ \t]*([^\n\r]*)\s*"
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        For Each objMatch In .Execute(strCont)
            objCatalog.Add objMatch.SubMatches(0), Array(objMatch.SubMatches(1), objMatch.SubMatches(2))
        Next
    End With
    For Each objElt In Range("D2:D10")
        With objElt
            If objCatalog.Exists(.Cells(1, 1).Value) Then
                .Offset(0, -1) = objCatalog(.Cells(1, 1).Value)(0)
                .Offset(0, -2) = objCatalog(.Cells(1, 1).Value)(1)
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Omegastripes, I tried using your fix with word 97-2004 (.doc) and I got the following compile error:

User-defined type not defined. 

It's pointing at the following line of code:

Dim objCatalog As Scripting.Dictionary

Can you let me know if I'm doing anything wrong? Also the word documents are in the 2011 format of word (.docx). Do I have to change anything?

Thanks in advance and thanks for taking a stab at this.

Comment: Since early binding used - you have to add some components to your project: open your project in Excel VBA editor, press `Menu` - `Tools` - `References`, then check the components I've listed at the beginning of my code. Choose appropriate version of Word Object Lib (11.0 corresponds to 2003). For `*.docx` no additional changes needed, just specify the actual filename instead of `catalog.doc`.

Comment: Hi omegastripes, I am receiving the following error:

Runtime error 429:

ActiveX component can't be created. 

   With CreateObject("Word.Application") is highlighted by the debugger. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That's unexpected flop.. Check if your MS Office installed properly. `Word.Application` key must exists in the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT registry branch to be able to create the ActiveX instance with that ProgID.
Have you tried to add the references to your project to perform early binding (first sub in my answer)? What is your MS Office version from `Word`|`Excel` - `Menu` - `Help` - `About`?

Comment: Hi omegastripes, I looked in the references option and the only selectable options are: 

Visual basic for applications
Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object library
Microsoft forms 2.0 Object library
Microsoft office 14.0 Object library
Microsoft visual basic of applications
Microsoft word 14.0 object library
Chart 14 type library
Microsoft graph 14.0 object library
Microsoft powerpoint 14.0 object library
OLE automation

The version of excel I'm using is:

Microsoft excel for Mac 2011
Version 14.3.9

It's a legit copy with key. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Turns out, you are using Mac! Try to start with my second code block, add the reference to `Microsoft word 14.0 object library` you mentioned above, and replace the line `With CreateObject("Word.Application")` with `With New Word.Application`. Unfortunately, I am not a pro in Mac OS, so I can't give you valuable advice about early and late binding in that VBA. My clue is to add `osx` label to your question to attract the experts.

Comment: Hi omegastripes, thank for the help - it worked. Sorry for the late reply, I've been away on business and I didn't have many chances to go online. I really appreciate the help!